# Can you import multiple CSS files in a Webpack config without using import on the JavaScript entry script?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

Is there a way to import CSS via webpack without using import within js?

For example if i split all my CSS up into clean files for each component i don't want to import them all one by one in the JS, i just want to build and it include everything in the folder automatically.

My webpack config looks like below:

```
 const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

console.log('path : ', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'scss'));

module.exports = {
    output : {
        filename : 'bundle.js',
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/static')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, sourceMap: true } },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader', },
                    { loader: 'postcss-loader' }
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "style.css"
        })

    ],
    mode : devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
    devServer: {
        allowedHosts: [
            'joblot-trophies.local',
        ],
        publicPath: '/assets/',
        overlay: true,
        inline: true,
    },
}
```

Comment: I would advice to add some code you have tried into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the changes of having your question flagged and removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

Example:

```
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css");
    module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css(\?|$)/,
            use: extractCSS.extract({
              use: isDevBuild ? "css-loader" : "css-loader?minimize"
            })
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [extractCSS]
    };
```